# How to update model via WebSocket?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to update my model via WebSocket, I made it in next way:

```
socket.on('message', function (jsonObj) {
   if (jsonObj.action && jsonObj.action == 'consultationReload')
    {
        self.store.all('consultation').forEach(function(c) {
            if (c.get('id') == jsonObj.consultationId) {
                c.reload();
            }
        });
        return;
    }
```

But `c.reload()` makes request to API. And I think it extra request I could attach these data to message from websocket. But question is how to reload model with these json data from websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all of the records from the store, just `push` the record into the store.  Any record that is already in the store will be updated, any record that isn't there will get inserted.

```
this.store.push('consultation', {
  id: 2,
  title: "Calgary b/w I Can't Make You Love Me/Nick Of Time",
  artist: "Bon Iver",
  songCount: 2
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushMany

Comment: I tried that but Consultation model joined with User model and Records model. And `c.reload()` updates all joined models, but `push` updates only Consultation model. So do I need to call `push` for each model?

Comment: If you have the other model's records

Comment: `this.store.pushPayload('consultation', jsonObj.consultationData);` It works for me. But I have one more question if I want to update only User model how do I need to tell to joined Consultation model that User model was updated? Because I tried to do `this.store.push('user', userData);` and when I try to get in Consultation model `this.get('user.status')` to compute some property I get old value of user.status